# How to make ImpressJS work on IE10?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-10, polyfills, impress.js

I am not able to make impressJS work on IE10. I wanted to know which all polyfills are required to be inserted in order to make impressJS work ?

Comment: What do you mean you cannot make it work on IE10? ImpressJS is compatible with it.

Comment: @RoyDictus Yes I am not able to Run it on IE10. I wanted to know the list of polyfills

Answer (score 1):

ImpressJS requires support for HTML 5 [dataset](http://caniuse.com/#search=dataset), which IE 10 doesn't fully support.

I was able to get Impress 0.5.3 to run in IE 10 by using the HTML 5 dataset shim:
https://gist.github.com/brettz9/4093766.